Issuing building --Static linked executables with GraalVm Docker community Image containers
Describe the issue
I am unable to build a statically linked executable using native-image with the musl libc on GraalVM. The build process fails with a segmentation fault.
I am, however, able to produce dynamically linked executables without issues.


Steps to reproduce the issue

Clone repo git@github.com:aahx/graalvm-docker.git
branch attempt/michael/muslib

(pretty much a "Hello World")

Build the project and create native image using Docker.
The Dockerfile is :

FROM ghcr.io/graalvm/native-image-community:22.0.1-muslib-ol9-20240416

RUN microdnf install -y gzip tar && microdnf clean all

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN ./mvnw clean package
RUN native-image --no-fallback --static --libc=musl -jar /app/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/target/demo

Building with $ docker build -t test1 .


Describe GraalVM and your environment:

GraalVM 22 / 21/ 17 (attempted multiple docker image containers)
java 21.0.1 2023-10-17 LTS Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 21.0.1+12-LTS-29) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.1+12-LTS-29, mixed mode, sharing)
Sonoma 14.5
Apple Silicon Apple M2



More details
The build fails with the following error message
    ========================================================================================================================
GraalVM Native Image: Generating 'demo' (static executable)...
========================================================================================================================
Warning: The host machine does not support all features of 'x86-64-v3'. Falling back to '-march=compatibility' for best compatibility.
[1/8] Initializing...                                                                                    (8.9s @ 0.06GB)
 Java version: 22.0.1+8, vendor version: GraalVM CE 22.0.1+8.1
 Graal compiler: optimization level: 2, target machine: compatibility
 C compiler: x86_64-linux-musl-gcc (linux, x86_64, 10.2.1)
 Garbage collector: Serial GC (max heap size: 80% of RAM)
 1 user-specific feature(s):
 - com.oracle.svm.thirdparty.gson.GsonFeature
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Build resources:
 - 5.79GB of memory (75.6% of 7.66GB system memory, determined at start)
 - 8 thread(s) (100.0% of 8 available processor(s), determined at start)
[2/8] Performing analysis...  [#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ffffee2ecd4, pid=31, tid=53
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 22.0.1+8.1 (22.0.1+8) (build 22.0.1+8-jvmci-b01)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 22.0.1+8.1 (22.0.1+8-jvmci-b01, mixed mode, tiered, jvmci, jvmci compiler, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, parallel gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0xd5ccd4]  oopDesc* PSPromotionManager::copy_unmarked_to_survivor_space<false>(oopDesc*, markWord)+0x44
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /app/hs_err_pid31.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues
#
Error: Image build request for 'demo' (pid: 31, path: /app/target) failed with exit status 134




Additional
I am able to use FROM ghcr.io/graalvm/native-image-community:22 and run:
RUN native-image --no-fallback -jar /app/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/target/demo


to produce a dynamically linked executable without any issues. The problem only occurs when using musl libc and attempting to create a statically linked executable.
Have also tried variations of
ghcr.io/graalvm/native-image-community:22-muslib-ol8
ghcr.io/graalvm/native-image-community:21-muslib
ghcr.io/graalvm/native-image-community:17-muslib 


Maybe this has to do with the fact that the build is performed in a Mac(an M2 mac)? In my ubuntu laptop, I'm able to build the dockerfile in the question just fine. I even added an extra stage to produce a tiny docker image and I see the message Native Image is awesome when I run that image
